# How much memory can my application use? or what is usual?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory, memory-management

i have been testing my application on 4 IOS devices. 1 ipod touch 2g, 1 iPhone 3gs, two iPhone 4's. On the iPhone 4's my application will take up about 30-50mb of memory while running. On the 3Gs it will take about 15-30mb, and on the iPod it will take about 15-27mb of memory.

Is there any kind of rule against how much memory your application can use? The app doesnt crash on any of them, but i thought i read somewhere that the max is like 20mb of memory usage?

Frankly im surprised that the iPod touch 2g is able to run the thing, i was told that the max youll ever get out of iPod 2g is like 20 mb of ram.

Now i have another question, while running Instruments, does it add any amount of memory usage on the device? It seems like while running instruments the application lags more than when not running with it.

Thanks,
Jacob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will usually get a memory warning when you hit 22 MB. Instruments does slow down the processing but it does not add any additional memory usage on the device.

Comment: @Jacob No but you will get a the callback - (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning

Comment: From what i see, on the iPod 2g when it hits 27mb it then is able to free up memory and push it back down to 20-25mb

Comment: @Jacob Yes the application will try to clean everything it can when it is running low in memory, newer devices of course have more memory available.

Answer (score 10):

There is no exact limit.  Technically, your app can use "up to the total amount of memory currently available", but that amount will vary depending upon things like device model, iOS version, what other apps are running in the background, and so on.

Speaking *very* generally, if you want your app to run reliably on older devices like the iPhone 3G you should shoot for 10-15 MB of RAM.  For newer devices 30+ MB should not be a problem.  Meaning that while it's always good to reduce this amount if you can, your app should still function okay even if you don't.

Also note that the memory warnings sent by the device are not very useful or indicative of a specific memory limit.  They are not saying that your app is using too much memory in any absolute sense.  Instead they just say that the current device, with its current working-set of apps, is running low on memory.  You can [safely ignore them](http://codethink.no-ip.org/wordpress/archives/455) if you prefer, and let the OS shut down some other apps to make room for yours.

Regarding instruments lagging the app, instruments is polling the device for details about the application's current state and other historical information.  There is overhead associated with collecting and communicating this information.  In terms of impact on the space requirements for your app, they should be negligible, however.

Comment: My app loads lots of view controllers, and when one is loaded it just keeps taking and taking more and more memory. If i were to be able to get it to return some of the memory from a pervious controller, then i wold be at like 10mb

Comment: So then why not release the old controller when you transition to the new one?

Comment: MainViewController *menuGo = [[MainViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MainView" bundle:nil];
    
    menuGo.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:menuGo animated:YES];
    [menuGo release];
    I do this, but it still keeps taking more. As far as releasing the controller, im not sure how to do that

Comment: @Jacob - you could perform some static analysis on the codebase (can't remember if you need XCode 4.2 for that though). That will run through your code and find any missing releases you have.

Comment: This is inconsistent with what I am observing.  The same application on iOS4 declares about 25MB of free memory, then gets a low-memory warning.  On iOS5 I see upwards of 110MB of free memory, so it does not get the low-memory warning.